# How can SDL tell what Xbox360 controller is what player?

Tags: c++, sdl, xbox-controller

I init my controllers like this:

```
if (SDL_WasInit(SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER) == 1)
    return;
SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER);

int nJoysticks = SDL_NumJoysticks();
numGamepads = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nJoysticks; i++)
    if (SDL_IsGameController(i))
        numGamepads++;

if (numGamepads > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numGamepads; i++)
    {
        SDL_GameController* pad = SDL_GameControllerOpen(i);
        if (SDL_GameControllerGetAttached(pad) == 1)
            joysticks.push_back(pad);
        else
            cout << "SDL_GetError() = " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    }
    SDL_GameControllerEventState(SDL_ENABLE);
}
```

and I poll events like this:

```
SDL_Event sdl_Event;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&sdl_Event))
{
    switch (sdl_Event.type)
    {
    case SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEADDED:
        cout << "DEVICEADDED cdevice.which = " << sdl_Event.cdevice.which << endl;
        break;
    case SDL_CONTROLLERBUTTONDOWN:
        cout << "BUTTONDOWN cdevice.which = "<< sdl_Event.cdevice.which << endl;
        HandleGamepadButtonsDown(sdl_Event);
        break;
    case SDL_CONTROLLERBUTTONUP:
        HandleGamepadButtonsUp(sdl_Event);
        break;
    case SDL_CONTROLLERAXISMOTION:
        HandleGamepadAxis(sdl_Event);
        break;
    case SDL_QUIT:
        _quit = true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

With this I have currently two Xbox 360 controllers connected. On these pads there is a LED indicating if it is player 1, 2, 3, or 4.

[image: Player 1]

When I run this my poll loop prints out this when I press a button on this controller:

[image: I press a button on player 1's controller]

When I hit a button on the controller with the player 2 LED it prints:

[image: I press a button on player 2's controller]

So that is wrong. How can I from inside the code find out what controller corresponds to the controller with the right LED light on?

Also, when I first start it then it prints:

[image]

So the controllers are 0 and 1 when I add them but 1 and 2 when I run the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `cdevice` isn't safe to use on a `SDL_CONTROLLERBUTTONDOWN` event. It could contain whatever field of a `SDL_ControllerButtonEvent` happens to overlap the `which` field of the `SDL_ControllerDeviceEvent` structure in the union inside `SDL_Event`.

So the SDL docs are a little confusing on this, but here's what I could gather:

There are two different "instances" that are passed around from the game controller events. There are game controller instance IDs, which is used in the `SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICE*` events, and then there are joystick instance IDs, which are used for an example in the `SDL_CONTROLLERBUTTONDOWN` event.

Here's what the docs say about the `which` field for button events:

> Type: SDL_JoystickID - Name: which - Description: the joystick instance id

and here's the same `which` parameter on a `SDL_ControllerDeviceEvent`:

> Type: Sint32 - Name: which - the joystick device index for the SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEADDED event or instance id for the SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEREMOVED or SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEREMAPPED event

The biggest (and pretty much only) giveaway here is the different types of the fields.

A game controller in SDL is a combination of multiple joystick instances or something, and this is why it all becomes quite confusing.

So here's what I do in my codebase to make sure the correct player instance receives the correct controller events (so that pressing a button on one controller doesn't make all players perform an action):

Since `SDL_CONTROLLERBUTTONDOWN` events have a joystick instance field, I compare the `which` field of the event to `SDL_JoystickInstanceID(SDL_GameControllerGetJoystick(controller));`, where `controller` is a `SDL_GameController*` that's supposed to control the player.

I do keep track of the `which` value of the `SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEADDED` event too inside my controller-wrapper class, so that I can properly handle `SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEREMOVED` events.

So in conclusion, it's a little messy to get things going, but once you have your `bool DoesThisEventBelongToThisController(SDL_Event* event, SDL_GameController* controller);` function setup, you shouldn't have to worry about this anymore.

Comment: Can you tell me why the cdevice.which id is different in SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEADDED and SDL_CONTROLLERBUTTONDOWN?

Comment: For `SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEADDED` `cdevice.which` is the joystick device index, while with `SDL_CONTROLLERBUTTONDOWN` `cdevice.which` probably maps to the same address as `cbutton.which` (as to how unions work, feel free to look unions up if you're not familiar with them. `SDL_Event` is essentially one large union.), and `cbutton.which` is a joystick instance id, not a joystick device index. But as I said, you should not access `cdevice` in a `SDL_CONTROLLERBUTTONDOWN` handler.

Comment: I get the same problem when I switch everything to jdevice.which

Comment: You switch to what? Anyways, I clearly mention in the answer that the values in `cbutton.which` dont correspond directly to `cdevice.which`. They're two different types of values, that have different meanings. And don't switch everything, just use `cbutton` when handling button events, and use `cdevice` when handling device events.

Comment: I accepted this answer even though it was not 100% what I was asking for. If you unplug and replug a lot of controllers making "holes" in the controller order according the LEDs. Then the controller ID in SDL will not reflect the LED on the controller. But this was close enough.